# PHP Button limit

Tags: php

Okay I have a problem here. Whether users column "checked" is 1 or 0 it ignores the IF statement and still adding 10000 points. Can somebody explain me why ?

```
foreach ($users as $u) {

    if (isset($username) . $u['checked'] == 0) {

        foreach ($points as $p) {

            $username = $_SESSION['username'];

            $p = $p['points'] + 10000;

            try {
                $q = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET points = ?, checked = ? WHERE username = ?");
                $q->execute(array($p, $ten, $username));
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
                die();
            }

            header("Location: index.php");
        }
    } else {
        echo "Nothing";
    }
}
```

Comment: What should be this `if(isset($username).$u['checked'] == 0) {`?

Comment: How then do I need to check if users column "checked" is 1 or 0 ?

Comment: 1. as @FLD said - $username is not set
2. what is $points? it is not visible anywhere in you snippet
3. I would say that that if(isset($username).$u['checked'] == 0) evaluates as false because of 1. - username is not set and the rest of the If statement is simply omitted

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (isset($u['username']))` ? Assuming `$u` is an array of user information return from a query or something...

Comment: I would say that there shouldn't be a dot there

Comment: Okay now it shows "nothing" second time. But when I again changed the same users "checked" column to 0 it again shows "Nothing"

Comment: If column "checked" is set to 1 for only one user, anothers also cannot click the button...

Answer (score 0):

Try using a more explicit if statement like

```
if(isset($username) && $u['checked'] == 0)
```

Also as Bery said in the comments, isn't $username supposed to be $u?